# passing header data in .NET and IIS

Tags: php, asp.net, .htaccess, asp.net-mvc-4, iis

I have existing code that passes information for a video file in php to the video player through .htaccess. I'm trying to understand how something like this can be replicated in IIS and .NET

php script:

```
$hash = $_GET['h'];
$streamname = $_GET['v'];
$timestamp = $_GET['t'];
$current = time();
$token = 'sn983pjcnhupclavsnda';
$checkhash = md5($token . '/' . $streamname . $timestamp);

if (($current - $timestamp) <= 2 && ($checkhash == $hash)) {
  $fsize = filesize($streamname);
  header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' . $streamname . '"');
  if (strrchr($streamname, '.') == '.mp4') {
    header('Content-Type: video/mp4');
  } else {
    header('Content-Type: video/x-flv');
  }
  header('Content-Length: ' . $fsize);
  session_cache_limiter('nocache');
  header('Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT');
  header('Last-Modified: ' . gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s') . ' GMT');
  header('Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
  header('Pragma: no-cache');
  $file = fopen($streamname, 'rb');
  print(fread($file, $fsize));
  fclose($file);
  exit;
} else {
  header("location:.$player_id");
}
```

.htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on


RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)/(.*)$ videoSecure.php?h=$1&t=$2&v=$3

RewriteRule ^$ - [F]
RewriteRule ^[^/]+\.(flv|mp4)$ - [F]
```

What this does is obfuscate and secure a video file from being downloaded directly off the sever, but still allowing it to be streamed.

I'm trying to understand if I can achieve something like this in IIS6/7 + .NET MVC4

Alternatively, would I be able to keep the php and have it execute through IIS despite a .NET environment for the majority of the site and would that produce any problems?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use some thing like this.

```
Response.AppendHeader("Content-Type", "video/mp4");
```